# Page Numbers are displayed in reverse such as 21 for page 12 in ConTeXt MarkIV

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, context, context-mkiv, arabic

I am trying to typeset a book in arabic in ConTeXt. I have stumbled upon this issue

Page Numbers change after 9 
to 01 for page 10
21 for page 12
31 for page 13
41 for page 14
and so on

The issue seems to be with

> \setupheader[style=\righttoleft, state=normal]

I need the righttoleft setting for the arabic text to appear correctly in the header.

Here is the snapshot of the page number issue:
[image]

Here is my ConTeXt Code:

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]

\setupdirections[bidi=global]

\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,tlig=yes,
    calt=yes,trep=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Bold] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [Arabic-Bold]    [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Arabic]
  \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default] 
\stoptypescript 



\setupmargindata[margintext]
    [align=r2l]

\setupalign[r2l]  


\setuppapersize[A4]


\setuplayout[
  grid=min,
  backspace=46.666mm, width=140mm,
  topspace=33.000mm, height=198mm,
  header=12.9mm,footer=9mm,
  ]


%% Double sided document
\setuppagenumbering[
  alternative=doublesided,
  state=none,
  location={header,marginedge},
%  conversion=romannumerals, left={--~}, right={~--},
]


\setupbodyfont[Arabic,18pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=42pt]


\setupheads[number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][style=\bfd,before=,after=\blank,alternative=middle,grid=both]
\setuphead[section][style=\bfc,before=\blank,after=,grid=both]

\setupbackgrounds[text][text][frame=off, topframe=on]

\setupheader[style=\righttoleft, state=normal]     

\setupheadertexts
        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]    [{\pagenumber}]
        [{\pagenumber}]        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]



\starttext
\chapter{شرح الآجرومية}
الحمد لله رب العالمين، وصلى الله وسلم وبارك على عبده ورسوله نبينا محمد وعلى آله وصحبه أجمعين، أما بعد:\\
\stoptext
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on both the ConTeXt mailing list and here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem like the command `\righttoleft` reverse the  order of numbers in header, you can maintain `\pagenumber` to be written from left to right as follows

```
\let\Pagenumber\pagenumber
\def\pagenumber{\hbox{\textdir TLT\Pagenumber}}
```

or

```
\let\Pagenumber\pagenumber
    \def\pagenumber{\hbox{\lefttoright\Pagenumber}}
```

---

**Code**

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]

\setupdirections[bidi=global]

\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,tlig=yes,
    calt=yes,trep=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Bold] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [Arabic-Bold]    [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Arabic]
  \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default] 
\stoptypescript 



\setupmargindata[margintext]
    [align=r2l]

\setupalign[r2l]  


\setuppapersize[A4]


\setuplayout[
  grid=min,
  backspace=46.666mm, width=140mm,
  topspace=33.000mm, height=198mm,
  header=12.9mm,footer=9mm,
  ]


%% Double sided document
\setuppagenumbering[
  alternative=doublesided,
  state=none,
  location={header,marginedge},
%  conversion=romannumerals, left={--~}, right={~--},
]


\setupbodyfont[Arabic,18pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=42pt]


\setupheads[number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][style=\bfd,before=,after=\blank,alternative=middle,grid=both]
\setuphead[section][style=\bfc,before=\blank,after=,grid=both]

\setupbackgrounds[text][text][frame=off, topframe=on]

\setupheader[style=\righttoleft, state=normal]     

\let\Pagenumber\pagenumber
\def\pagenumber{\hbox{\textdir TLT\Pagenumber}}

\setupheadertexts
        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]    [{\pagenumber}]
        [{\pagenumber}]        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]



\starttext
\chapter{شرح الآجرومية}
الحمد لله رب العالمين، وصلى الله وسلم وبارك على عبده ورسوله نبينا محمد وعلى آله وصحبه أجمعين، أما بعد:\\
\stoptext
```